# Can JMeter do automation testing like Selenium can do?

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests

i am still new to JMeter and i was assigned to a work that I will need to use JMeter to perform automation testing. The idea is to write script using JMeter and run the script to fill in the forms in the website. I was curious that can JMeter use different data from the database to fill in the form of the website everytime it execute?(unique data for every user)

I have followed this tutorial (https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/fill-forms-and-submit-with-jmeter-made-easy/ ) and it succeed, however, when i try to change the parameter name (to some other names that do not matches the field name found in the inpect mode), it still works. So i was wondering how JMeter knows where to put in the parameter even i have change to a wrong field name?

Answer (score 1):

As per [JMeter Project](http://jmeter.apache.org/) main page:

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

Browsers don't do any magic, they execute [HTTP Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods), wait for response and render it. JMeter in its turn can execute the same HTTP requests so traffic would be the same, however it will not render the response, but rather measure the time and collect some more metrics.

If you change the names of the inputs in the [form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) most probably the request will be successful, to wit you will get [HTTP Status Code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 hence JMeter will mark the result as "green", however if you inspect the response using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener you will see that the form is not filled and/or you still at the same page.

If you want to use JMeter for checking the data returned by the application you're testing consider using [JMeter Assertions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps/) to test presence of expected values, absence of errors, set response time thresholds, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate the form submission or order placement usin JMeter. You can JMeter for API testing as well by adding assertions. But the main purpose of the JMeter is to test the performance of the application. Its not like selenium which performs actions on the **browser** whereas JMeter sends the request in various **protocols** to relevant server and can also simulate many users at the same time.

If you want to do extensive automation testing,JMeter isnt the ideal tool for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use webdriver sampler to run the selenium with jmeter. It requires to configure sampler and browser config which are plugin and can be downloaded using plugin manager.

For more info:-https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler/

Now, without the plugin it is working on protocol level and not on the frontend as pointed out in the above comments.
So, yes it can depend on which layer you want to work. It can work on frontend like selenium using the webdriver plugin and can submit the form with different data as a direct request to the server without using the frontend/GUI.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to automate. If you plan to automate API invocation where there are some pre-requisites like grabbing tokens, cookies, session IDs from the browser, then JMeter can probably be used where existing JMeter capabilities can be leveraged using **BeanShell** scripting and other plugins.

But if you plan to have a full blown UI automation framework then JMeter might not be an ideal choice.